# Creating custom initial projection in GMT/GDAL

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I have a number of images which I need to project into the standard IAU 2000 lunar coordinate system. Each is defined in terms of an oblique cylindrical projection, and I am given the rotation pole/angle for each image plus some information on extent.

GDAL seemed the most appropriate tool to use, so following this guide:
https://proj.org/operations/projections/ocea.html

I tried the following but received an error:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=ocea +lonc=72.10118887673107 +alpha=-147.31979949126344 +lon_0=-25.29391507932755 +R=1737400" -co SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM unmapped.tif mapped.tif
ERROR 1: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for test.tif. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.
```

Adding `-co src_method=no_geotransform` had no effect on the error.

Clearly I've missed something, but since it required only the pole longitude and rotation I'm baffled what's missing. Projection details are below.

```
oblique.pole.rotation=-147.31979949126344
bodyradius=1737.4
oblique.pole.latitude=4.776013070135473
extent.southern=45.60718942659914
reference.latitude=57.010975400021486
extent.western=-34.829414717107454
oblique.pole.longitude=72.10118887673107
resolution.x=15161.675212074742
extent.northern=68.24339505742044
resolution.y=1516.1675212074742
oblique.axis.z=0.3062697383844906,0.9482966365802304,0.08326065337551693
extent.eastern=-20.263914598221046
oblique.axis.x=0.49227810375547126,-0.23263483412483185,0.8387748819049301
oblique.axis.y=0.8147767276455637,-0.21590396708336387,-0.5380746798399387
reference.longitude=-25.29391507932755
```

Comment: The gdalwarp utility is warping images from one coordinate system into another. Does it understand what is the crs of your source image? What does gdalinfo say? If the source crs cannot be detected automatically you can tell it with `-s_srs`.

Comment: Thanks for replying! It most likely does not because the source image has no crs. I'm looking into gdal_grid now as a possibility to give it one with the extent information I have.

Comment: When you know suitable parameters for the initial crs of your image you can attach the CRS info with for example gdal_edit.py, or by creating a copy of the source image with gdal_translate and parameter `-a_srs`. Gdal_grid creates a raster file from vector data (points) by interpolation. It does not feel like a correct tool for you. If the source image is not georeferenced at all you can perhaps georeference it by using ground control points with known coordinates.

Comment: Ah I see. Will try gdal_edit then, thanks for the advice. Unfortunately this isn't earth data so there aren't any well-referenced basemaps to set control points. But edit looks promising...